# How to make it so that theres a wait time between dialog

Tags: java

how would i make it so that in between the System.out.println theres a pause, so it doesnt all spill out at once,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Stranger: Good morning");
    System.out.println("Stranger: you had a terrible Dream..");
    System.out.println("Stranger: what is your name?");
    System.out.print("Name:");
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner (System.in); 
    String s = kbReader.next();
    System.out.println("Nice to meet you " + s);
    System.out.println("my name is Master Wizard.");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would have thought that the scanner would stop until you enter something and press the enter key

Comment: it does, but i would like it so that the
    System.out.println("Stranger: Good morning");
    System.out.println("Stranger: you had a terrible Dream..");
    System.out.println("Stranger: what is your name?");
so theres a little time for them to read it

Comment: What type of pause do you want?  A delay (like 1 second) or do you want the user to have to press a key

Comment: You need `Thread.sleep(1000)` (to wait 1 second for instance).

Comment: unreported exception error /:

Comment: `try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(InterruptedException e){}`

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes that would be perfect

Comment: @johnchen902 i saw this on a diffrent website i still got an error, would it be something with the ide im using?

Comment: You could also throw the interruptedException, I can't imagine why such a simple program would throw this exception.

Comment: @Oxide_Sickness What error did you get?

Comment: illegal start of type, lol should i make a new line? cause im puting it right under it, and fixing it

Comment: System.out.println("Stranger: Good morning");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
    }

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Stranger: Good morning");
        delay(500);
        System.out.println("Stranger: you had a terrible Dream..");
        delay(500);
        System.out.println("Stranger: what is your name?");
        System.out.print("Name:");
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = kbReader.next();
        System.out.println("Nice to meet you " + s);
        System.out.println("my name is Master Wizard.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void delay(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
        }
    }
}
```

For example

Comment: reached end of file parising

Comment: I've updated it with a working example, not all code presented will magically work outside of it's context ;)